# Vpython no such file : Error while building gradle Chromium android studio

Tags: android, python-3.x, chromium, chromium-os

I am trying to import Chromium for Android as an Android Studio project on an Ubuntu 16.04(LTS).

I have completed the below steps to build chromium project for Android

https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/android_build_instructions.md#Installing-and-Running-Chromium-on-a-device/

**Problem** : To create the Gradle file for importing the project into Android Studio I have referred to https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/android_studio.md

```
build/android/gradle/generate_gradle.py --output-directory out/Default
```

On running the above command I get the **error**:

```
usr/bin/env : "vpython' : no such file or directory.
```

Python 3.5.2 is installed on the system

**P.S:**
Vpython: https://chromium.googlesource.com/infra/infra/+/master/doc/users/vpython_one_page.md

Comment: did you fixed this problem? @Rachita Nanda

Answer (score -2):

yeah ,i have same problem..

because i not setting env with depot_tools.

so you just need to execute code below;

and DEPOT_PATH is you depot_tools 's an

```
export PATH=$DEPOT_PATH:$PATH
```